# jQuery listener for horizontal swipe on touchscreen?

Tags: jquery, detect, touchscreen

How can I detect a left to right swipe on touch screens with jQuery?

Comment: Hi, I have a page where the whole area is swipeable (to take you to the next page) but a part of that is an iframe. At the moment that part doesn't swipe - can you recommend something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.netcu.de/jquery-touchwipe-iphone-ipad-library

This libary seems to work fine and is only 1K

Comment: Hi, I have a page where the whole area is swipeable (to take you to the next page) but a part of that is an iframe. At the moment that part doesn't swipe - can you recommend something?

Comment: This plugin is incredible. Really impressive how light-weight it is and how accurate too. Thanks @jdln. A bummer that the go-away-already strict SO police flagged this question as too broad.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the [jquery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) and its [`swiperight`-event.](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/api/events.html)

Comment: I cant use jQuery mobile as it would mean remaking my entire site in the format they need. thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: And moreover jquery mobile is a pure ****** so heavy and never work as expected, just good to loose time ;-(